# Create custom search via Automator->Service

Tags: osx-elcapitan, automator

As I think of ways to reduce steps, I was curious if anyone might have an answer to this conundrum.  I'd like to be able to create a right-click->context menu to search text while on Craigslist.  Specifically, find a car/motorcycle of interest, select the text via highlight, right-click, Service->search fuelly.com/car or fuelly.com/motorcycle.  Anyone ever do anything similar in Automator?